# Notifying view controller of changes to any of five types of models

Tags: mvc, swift, generics, swift3

I have a swift 3 project with a code that's look like very generic, but I don't know if I can reduce a method like this one :

```
var pages: [Page] // List of page object

func RefreshList(){
        guard let currentIndex = currentIndex else { return }

        if let listTableViewController: listTableViewController<ModelA> = pages[currentIndex].viewController as? listTableViewController<ModelA> {
            listTableViewController.didRefreshNodesList()
        }
        else if let listTableViewController: listTableViewController<ModelB> = pages[currentIndex].viewController as? listTableViewController<ModelB> {
            listTableViewController.didRefreshNodesList()
        }
        else if let listTableViewController: listTableViewController<ModelC> = pages[currentIndex].viewController as? listTableViewController<ModelC> {
            listTableViewController.didRefreshNodesList()
        }
        else if let listTableViewController: listTableViewController<ModelD> = pages[currentIndex].viewController as? listTableViewController<ModelD> {
            listTableViewController.didRefreshNodesList()
        }
        else if let listTableViewController: listTableViewController<ModelE> = pages[currentIndex].viewController as? listTableViewController<ModelE> {
            listTableViewController.didRefreshNodesList()
        }
    }
```

The only things that change is the Model(LETTER) is there a way to reduce that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type annotation in

```
if let listTableViewController: listTableViewController<ModelA> = pages[currentIndex].viewController as? listTableViewController<ModelA>
```

is not needed because the type is automatically inferred from the
expression on the right-hand side:

```
if let listTableViewController = pages[currentIndex].viewController as? listTableViewController<ModelA>
```

---

According to the Swift [API Design Guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines)

> Names of types and protocols are `UpperCamelCase`. Everything else is `lowerCamelCase`.

Therefore it should be `func refreshList()` and `ListTableViewController`.

---

To simplify your code, define a *protocol* for the common methods:

```
protocol RefreshController {
    func didRefreshNodesList()
    // ...
}
```

and make `ListTableViewController` conform to that protocol.
Then you can reduce it to a single test

```
if let refreshController = pages[currentIndex].viewController as? RefreshController {
    refreshController.didRefreshNodesList()
}
```